How can I extract the text block on these labels that also contain a barcode?
I have a task that requires me to extract order details from pdf or image, in a structured format.
My approach was to locate the barcode area, then OCR the text above each barcode area.
The final output should look like this
[
    {"style": "value", "art": "value", "color": "value", "size": "value", "barcode": "value"},
    {"style": "value", "art": "value", "color": "value", "size": "value", "barcode": "value"}
]

I have tried to decode the barcodes with pyzbar library. It extracts the barcodes accurately, but the borders it draws are not accurate. Here is the result of decoding and drawing the borders on barcodes

I have also tried using chat gpt vision models, but the result is not stable in this case.
Here is the source image:


You should include the code that you have used to produce those results so that other people can try replicate. I've never used pyzbar but I might have been inclined to play with it, if I didn't need to start the whole thing from scratch

Mainly because the termination on the final EAN13 seems to be stable in being incorrect at where it cuts off

relax, especially in case you're just here for the python tag. I released this from the SG because I have an answer almost ready. one of my earlier answers starts the same way: detect the codes. then this one will differ. the ROIs that go into OCR need to be calculated relative to those codes, and perhaps also extracted (affine warp).

note: this question came from the SG. OP confirmed that the question is about grabbing those text blocks. -- I think the info in the text is also encoded in those barcodes, but that need not always be so.

Let's consider the barcode and text to be "a form". It consists of the text block and the barcode block.
The barcode works fine for locating each form. Another approach could try to locate the fixed text (style, art, color, size) instead of the barcode. That would be more involved though.
Approach:

locate barcode
step through some 2D transforms
get the text block

You've seen that pyzbar gives bad bounding boxes. When the barcode isn't upright but rotated, pyzbar might not even detect it, and even if it does, the bounding box has no orientation.
I've chosen OpenCV's BarcodeDetector. Its bounding boxes aren't perfect but good enough.
Unfortunately, this detector won't tell me which end of the box is the "beginning". So, if you can have barcodes that are upside down, you'll have to extract both possible regions and test. If not, then not. The barcode decoding step should have this information, but it didn't expose that. I can imagine an approach that can tell the orientation of a barcode without actually decoding it, from how the code's timing bars sit relative to the data bars. That would coincidentally improve the pose of the code (hence also the extracted text block's). I won't go into that just now. Let me know if that's relevant.
Visualization of the result:

green: barcode, the points on its "bounding" polygon, barcode's value
yellow: primary text box
orange: secondary text box


Extracted text boxes (primary left, secondary right):

And the code:
# imports

import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm, inv
import cv2 as cv

# utility functions

def normalize(vec):
    vec = np.asarray(vec)
    return vec / norm(vec)

def translate2(tx=0, ty=0):
    T = np.eye(3)
    T[0:2, 2] = (tx, ty)
    return T

def T_from_detection(detection):
    BL, TL, TR, BR = detection
    vx = normalize(TR - TL)
    vy = normalize(BL - TL)
    T = np.eye(3)
    T[0:2, 0] = vx
    T[0:2, 1] = vy
    T[0:2, 2] = TL
    return T

def polygon_from_wh(wh, dtype=None):
    (w, h) = wh
    return np.array([
        (0, 0),
        (w, 0),
        (w, h),
        (0, h)
    ], dtype=dtype)

def polygon_from_xywh(xywh):
    (x, y, w, h) = xywh
    return np.array([
        (x,     y),
        (x + w, y),
        (x + w, y + h),
        (x,     y + h)
    ])

# definitions
# consider each label as a form, with regions for the text and barcode

form_barcode_xy = (34, 138)

form_text_xywh = (0, 0, 400, 114)
text_wh = form_text_xywh[2:4]
text_polygon = polygon_from_wh(text_wh, dtype=np.float32)

T_form_text = translate2(*form_text_xywh[0:2])
T_form_barcode = translate2(*form_barcode_xy)

T_barcode_text = inv(T_form_barcode) @ T_form_text

# main code

im = cv.imread("f5SQQdP6-rotated.png", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

det = cv.barcode.BarcodeDetector()
(rv, codes, detections, straights) = det.detectAndDecodeMulti(img=im)

for detection, code in zip(detections, codes):
    T_world_code1 = T_from_detection(detection)
    T_world_code2 = T_from_detection(detection[[2, 3, 0, 1]]) # shuffle for the other orientation

    T_world_text1 = T_world_code1 @ T_barcode_text
    T_world_text2 = T_world_code2 @ T_barcode_text

    text_im1 = cv.warpPerspective(im, T_world_text1, text_wh, flags=cv.WARP_INVERSE_MAP | cv.INTER_CUBIC)
    text_im2 = cv.warpPerspective(im, T_world_text2, text_wh, flags=cv.WARP_INVERSE_MAP | cv.INTER_CUBIC)

    imshow(text_im1, text_im2) # my own shim for jupyter notebooks

All the visualization code elided. That's just a bunch of drawing calls and some perspectiveTransform() calls to transform points into various frames.
None of these things are actually perspective transforms. They're all affine. One could drop down to warpAffine() and transform(), but then those will need to be given T[0:2], which is the affine part (top two rows) of a 3x3 transform matrix.
